# Keycloak "Error: localhost request not supported" in Postman

Tags: docker, postman, authorization, token, keycloak

I want to use Keycloak for java springboot application microservices, I'm running it through Docker container, after installation and realm/users/clients creation I wanted to test it through Postman, but I get this error and the authentication is filed:

> Error: localhost request not supported.

In the console, I don't see any explanation of why it is happening.

Any help appreciated.

Keycloak is running on localhost:8088, I have a client on localhost:8080.

I took an OpenID endpoint configuration token of keycloak to tried to test it through postman (webbrowser version) to get a new Access Token, in Authorization I chose type: OAuth2.0 and provided all details for the token, clicking "get new access token" throws a new error

> localhost request not supported

instead of generating new access token.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with application version of postman. so if someone encounters the same problem with web browser version of postman, consider installing it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to make it work with desktop app ?

If I use desktop app, I get the following message

This dialogue will automatically close once the auth callback is received. Make sure your browser is not blocking pop-up window.

And in my browser :

Your call is authenticated
A new window should open directing you back to the Postman app. If nothing happens, check to make sure your browser allows pop-ups.

Btw, I allowed pop-up in Chrome